# CSS - Is it legal to add arbitrary unknown property names?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a chrome extension which manipulates the stylesheets of the page and want to store some extra information in the stylesheets themselves. Is it legal for me to simply create 'bogus' properties with values and then read them (ie using `styleElem.sheet.cssRules`) ?

Ie,

```
.myclass {
   background-color: yellow;
   bogus-property: 10;
}
```

thaks!

Comment: Can you use annotations? `/* this won't be evaluated */` (edit: sorry I didnt notice you were trying to read them also, but I will keep this for anyone's reference)

Comment: The file might load if you did `.myClass { /* ok */ }`. I notice that always calms my es lint when it gets mad about empty bodies.

Comment: Arbitrary properties won't break a stylesheet and prevent them from being read (the rules will just get crossed out), but I don't believe they'll be passed through to any style object in JS. Would be interested in seeing otherwise!

Comment: you won't get arrested for it, so, I think you're safe from the style police :p

Comment: you could use a fake prefix - prefixes are ignored by browsers which don't understand them...

Comment: thx  Jaromanda X, maybe safe now ? but future versions &different browsers ? what I'm interested in is if there is an official/standard answer

Comment: thx Johannes 2  - what do you mean by prefix ?

Comment: The CSS wouldn't be valid but may simply be ignored by the browser. Otherwise, you would need to build a helper class to parse the bogus property strings. What is the objective? Couldn't you address your requirements by using existing css and js specs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using custom properties in general are ignored and unreadable from a CSSStyleDeclaration.

But as long as you are using a supported browser, and know the property name you can use prefixed [Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*): properties prefixed with a double dash `--`, and meant to be used with the [var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) css function.

For example:

```
body {
    --my-property:30px;
}
```

To get this value through javascript, access the CSSStyleDeclaration of the containing stylesheet and call [getPropertyValue()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) with the full property name.

```
var style = document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style;
console.log( style.getPropertyValue('--my-property') );
```

Note if you are using an externally linked css file, you will need to use [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) on an element that has the property set on it. As style declarations are unreadable for external css.

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
console.log( style.getPropertyValue('--my-property') );
```

Demo

```js
var style = document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style;

console.log( style.getPropertyValue('--custom-property') );

console.log( style.getPropertyValue('--other-property') );
```

```css
body {
  --custom-property:30px;
  --other-property:url('some.jpg');
  font-size:var(--custom-property);
}
```

```html
Custom properties should be printed in console log of supporting browsers
```

Answer (score 3):

From the CSS 3 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#style-rules

> Declaration for an unknown CSS property or whose value does not match the syntax defined by the property are invalid and must be ignored. The validity of the style rule’s contents have no effect on the validity of the style rule itself.

So the browser is required to ignore stuff it doesn't understand, but not reject the surrounding properties because of it.

Comment: thx! but what does 'ignored' mean ? obviously they can't be applied, but can they still be read ? ie as in prefixes like Johannes 2 commented above ?

Comment: @kofifus: The spec is for the parser, which is reading all data. As long as you follow valid syntactic constructs, it will read through it to the semicolon or closing curly brace. When the custom value you presented is analyzed and found to be unknown, it will then simply be passed over. Not sure about retrieving it though.

Answer (score 1):

(moved from comments)

you could use a fake prefix - prefixes are ignored by browsers which don't understand them.

Like there is -webkit-justify-content as a webkit-specific definition of justify-content (which usually was created before the standard was equally implemented in all browsers), you could make up a prefix like `-mything-something` That should be ignored by all browsers since none of them has a "mything" engine...